Using Google Apps Script to Document File Information in a Shared Drive and Retrieve the Creator's Email
Process Overview
I'm working with a Google Sheet to document information about files in a shared Google Drive folder. The goal is to log details like file ID, title, URL, submission date and time, and the creator's email address. However, I'm facing an issue where I'm unable to retrieve the email of the user who created the document when using a shared drive.
Issue Encountered
Despite the script working to log file details, it fails to retrieve the email of the user who created the document in a shared drive. The error encountered is:
Request for Help
I'm looking for assistance on how to correctly retrieve the email of the user who created the document in a shared drive. Additionally, I'm planning to create an application using AppSheet for document approval and understanding, aimed at helping teachers. Is there another way to achieve this functionality? Any guidance or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.
`function checkNewFiles() {
  var folderId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FOLDER_ID'); // Substitua pelo ID da sua pasta
  var sheetId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('SHEET_ID'); // Substitua pelo ID da sua planilha

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[0];

  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var newFiles = [];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var createdDate = file.getDateCreated();
    var createdDay = Utilities.formatDate(createdDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var createdTime = Utilities.formatDate(createdDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'HH:mm:ss');

    Logger.log('Checking file: ' + file.getName() + ' created on ' + createdDate);

    // Verificar se o arquivo já está na planilha
    if (!isFileInSheet(sheet, file.getId())) {
      Logger.log('New file found: ' + file.getName());
      var creatorName = getFileOrganizerName(file.getId()); // Obter o nome do criador (fileOrganizer)
      newFiles.push([
        file.getId(),
        file.getName(),
        file.getUrl(),
        createdDay,
        createdTime,
        creatorName,
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
      ]);
    }
  }

  if (newFiles.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('New files to be added: ' + newFiles.length);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, newFiles.length, newFiles[0].length).setValues(newFiles);
  } else {
    Logger.log('No new files found.');
  }
}

// Função atualizada para obter o nome do fileOrganizer usando a API avançada do Google Drive
function getFileOrganizerName(fileId) {
  try {
    var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {fields: 'permissions'});
    if (file.permissions && file.permissions.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < file.permissions.length; i++) {
        if (file.permissions[i].role === 'organizer' || file.permissions[i].role === 'fileOrganizer') {
          return file.permissions[i].displayName;
        }
      }
    }
    return 'N/A';
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Unable to get organizer name for file: ' + fileId + ' - ' + e.message);
    return 'N/A';
  }
}

function isFileInSheet(sheet, fileId) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === fileId) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function setupSheet() {
  var sheetId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('SHEET_ID'); // Substitua pelo ID da sua planilha
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[0];

  var headers = ['ID', 'Title', 'URL', 'Submission Date', 'Submission Time', 'Teacher Name', 'Segment', 'Class', 'Approval Status', 'Approval Date', 'Comments'];
  sheet.getRange('A1:K1').setValues([headers]);
}

`


Can you provide the details of The error encountered is:?

I change the code, and return N/A dont show the e-mail or the name, i using SharedDrive.

Your English is better than mine! This script is in App Script, and its goal is to create a table that I can use in the future to develop an app using AppSheet. However, the only thing missing in this script is that it does not recognize the user, email, or name of the person who created the document within a shared Drive (not My Drive). The rules are different, and I cannot make the table column show the correct email or name of the document creator.

Thank you for replying. If I could correctly understand your reply, in that case, I think that the created user of the file cannot be directly retrieved because that is in the shared drive. But, the owner of the file will be the organizer of the shared drive. The email of the organizer can be retrieved by Drive API. If this was not your expected direction, I apologize.

Sorry about the delay to respond: i change the script, to drive api v3.
And the e-mail and name of user dont return... bur return the ID from user.
Whats i can do?
